# How Do I Stop This from Happening (brokenCount > 0)

Tags: package-management

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOc5c.png)
I Dont know what have caused it
and when i click prefrences it opens software and updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sudo apt-get -f install` It fixed my issue